# Triangles Chapter of Plane Geometry

Tags: geometry, triangles

If AD is the altitude through A of triangle ABC, prove that AB > AC, AB = AC or AB < AC according as BD > DC.,BD = DC or BD < DC

Comment: When you say stuff like "AB > AC", what are you referring to? Do you mean the length of the line segments? If so, please make that clear, as it will help us answer your questions more accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use Pythagoras theorem in the two triangles, namely $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ADC$, to obtain the result.

In $\triangle ABD$,

$$AB^2 = AD^2 + BD^2$$

In $\triangle ADC$,

$$AC^2 = AD^2 + DC^2$$

Now subtract the two and make your observations.